# Append binding data not replace with binding data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

i have a `TextBlock` `Text` target with a business object as a `Binding` `Source`, and this binding works fine with updates to the business object property propagating to the GUI, with the help of `INotifyPropertyChanged`

### Aim

The default behavior of such a binding is to replace the contents of the control such that say a second update to the business property will overwrite the display of the first update.

I would like the UI to display the first update, then **append the second update** and so forth, how might that be possible ?

### An Implementation?

1. Im not familiar with even the basic arsenal of wpf controls, would this be easier with a control other than TextBlock?
2. Or is it possible to do such binding with TextBlock?

It is undesirable for the business object to remember / store the previous updates.
I have already tried to use the `object parameter` in `IValueConverter` Convert method, but that does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the mvvm pattern and take a viewmodel to collect the propertychanged event data from your business object.

in this viewmodel create a

```
ObservableCollection<string>_myUpdateList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

proeprty to collect the data.

on UI(View) side i would take a itemscontrol, listbox or something like this and bind the ItemsSource to your ObservableCollection.

thats all. :)

Comment: sweet! do you happen to know how i could make the listbox wrap long lines? i.e. i used to be able to do `textBlock1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;` but am now to `listBox1.ItemsSource = _myUpdateList;`

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected for example. you can modify the itemtemplate textblock with WrapWithOverflow. if this did not work, just ask a new question on SO