# Changing RowDefinition of a ListView item on Tap

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin

What I'm trying to implement is a message chat bubble wherein you tap the control/message and the message would expand showing details of the date and the seen / sent status below. I do have a DataTemplate Selector for the different controls I have for the Sender and the Receiver.

**My problem is changing the Height of the message in the ListView.** I tried implementing the Binding of the RowDefinition to whatever the Height variable is in my Message class (the class that holds info regarding the message). Although the height was updated, it didn't reflect on the ListView. I've scoured over the internet for existing chat UI templates but I think most of them are paid. Hence, I'm trying to do follow [Change WPF DataTemplate for ListBox item if selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected). But for Xamarin, there's no ListBoxItem as there's only a ListView.

On a further note, I am working on Android and iOS. An example that is cross-platform to solve this will be greatly appreciated. Below are parts of my code.

datatemplate.cs

```
class MessageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public MessageTemplateSelector()
    {
        ReceiverDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MessageReceiver));
        SenderDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MessageSender));
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var message = item as Message;
        if (message == null)
            return null;
        return message.isSender ? ReceiverDataTemplate : SenderDataTemplate;
    }

    private readonly DataTemplate ReceiverDataTemplate;
    private readonly DataTemplate SenderDataTemplate;
}
```

MessageSender.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Project.layout.MessageSender">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Height}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Height}" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="{Binding Path=timestamp}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
            <Frame Padding="0" CornerRadius="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=text}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="15,10"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
            <Label Text="Seen" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
        </Grid>
  </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Message.cs

```
class Message
{
        public bool isSender { get; set; }
        public sbyte status { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public Message(bool isSender, sbyte status, string text, string timestamp)
        {
            this.isSender = isSender;
            this.status = status;
            this.text = text;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
        public sbyte height = 0;
        public sbyte Height { get { return height; }  set { height = value; } }
        bool selected = false;
        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return selected; }
            set { selected = value;if (value) { Height = 25; } else { Height = 0; } }
        }
    }
```

Show mainpage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.model"
             x:Class="Project.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MessageTemplateSelector x:Key="MessageTemplateSelector"></local:MessageTemplateSelector>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="conversation"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Message}"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                  ItemTapped="Conversation_ItemTapped"
                  Refreshing="Conversation_Refreshing">
        </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.cs

```
private void Conversation_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item == null) return;
    Message selectedItem = (Message)e.Item;
    Log.Debug("ItemTap","Height before:" + selectedItem.Height);
    if (selectedItem.Selected) { ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; selectedItem.Selected = false; }
    else { selectedItem.Selected = true; }
    Log.Debug("ItemTap", "Height after:" + selectedItem.Height);
}
```

This is a screenshot of my log that is present in the ItemTapped event in my ListView. As you can see, the height updates but it's not reflecting on the ListView.

[image: Proof that height updates on item tap]

Comment: you could try to get the parent `ViewCell` then call `viewCell.ForceUpdateSize ()` to update the size

Comment: and how would I do that? I tried `(sender as MessageSender).Parent.GetType().ToString()` and it gives me a null exception